# I have a data frame with two columns, A and B. Now, how can I store the data frame values in a list, separating them with commas and parentheses?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[0.8,0.23], [0.3,.40], [0.6,0.8], [0.7,0.9]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A','B'])
df
```

My expected output is

```
List= [(0.8,0.23), (0.3,.40), (0.6,0.8), (0.7,0.9)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative method:

```
data = [[0.8,0.23], [0.3,.40], [0.6,0.8], [0.7,0.9]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A','B'])

lst = [tuple(df.loc[x]) for x in df.index]
print(lst)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's the `to_record()` method.

Try using it:

```
data_list = list(df.to_records(index=False))
print(data_list)
```